# call html code in mysql

Tags: html, codeigniter, render

Below are my codeigniter controller & view. 
It stores new blog post using a form and tinymce editor. The problem is tinymce stores contents in html format. How do you call all stored contents in readable format.

Thanks

CONTROLLER CODE :

```html
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
               
 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('html');
  $this->load->model('blogpost');
 } 
 function index()
 {   
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('post', 'post', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[255]');   
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'content', 'max_length[255]');
   
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');
 
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
  {
   $this->load->view('BlogForm_view');
  }
  else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
  {
    // build array for the model
   
   $form_data = array(
             'post' => set_value('post'),
             'content' => set_value('content')
      );
     
   // run insert model to write data to db
  
   if ($this->blogpost->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
   {
    redirect('welcome/success'); 
      // or whatever logic needs to occur
   }
   else
   {
   echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
   // Or whatever error handling is necessary
   }
  }
 }
 function success()
 {
   echo 'this form has been successfully submitted with all validation being passed. All messages or logic here. Please note
   sessions have not been used and would need to be added in to suit your app';
 }

 function recall()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, post, content FROM post');

  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
  {
      echo $row['id'];
      echo $row['post'];
      echo $row['content'];
      $this->load->view('BlogForm_view');
  }
 }
}
?>
```

VIEW CODE :

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
  // General options
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced",
  plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

  // Theme options
  theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
  theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
  theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
  theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
  theme_advanced_resizing : true,

  // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
  content_css : "css/content.css",

  // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
  template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
  external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
  external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
  media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

  // Style formats
  style_formats : [
   {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
   {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
   {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
   {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
   {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
   {title : 'Table styles'},
   {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
  ],

  // Replace values for the template plugin
  template_replace_values : {
   username : "Some User",
   staffid : "991234"
  }
 });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
</head>
<body>

<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('welcome', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="post">post <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('post'); ?>
        <br />
        <input id="post" type="text" name="post" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo set_value('post'); ?>"  />
</p>
<p>
 <?php echo form_error('content'); ?>
<textarea name="content" class="tinyMCE"><?php echo set_value('content'); ?></textarea>
</p>

<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any database queries in the controller; that is the job of models.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using codeigniter correctly...

You shouldn't be doing any form of database query from your controller, that's the point of the model. Set up a function in the controller that communicates with the model instead. It's also usually cleaner to do all your data loops within the view instead of the controller (but that's my preference).

```
//Controller
function recall()
{
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->getPosts(); //Move to the model
    $this->load->view('BlogForm_view', $data); //Loop over data in the view.
}

//Model
function getPosts($post_id) {
    $this->db->select('id, post, content')->from('post');
    $r = $this->db->get();
    if ($r->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $r;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usually the point of using tinyMCE is to keep the associated html data. It looks like you're limiting that data to 255 characters. `$this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'content', 'max_length[255]');` If you're wanting to store html, you'll almost always want to store that as a longtext value in your database. Your question is phrased to sound like you don't want the html though. And if that's the case you can just use the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) method that php supplies to remove all the html (this would probably be in your model where you're dealing with the $this->input->post() data)